# Passing a Value from PHP to Javascript Variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've seen numerous posts on how to do this either saying to use `rawurlencode` in the php and `decodeURIComponent` in javascript or just use `json_encode`.  Neither work for me.  Hoping someone can see what I'm doing wrong:

I have an html button like this:

```
<button id="editbutton" onClick='edit(this, "<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>", "<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_type"]; ?>", "<?php echo rawurlencode($result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]); ?>")'>Edit</button>
```

I pass that into the javascript edit button:

```
var edit = function(t, to, cameratype, cameraname, cameraquality, camerahash, camerastatus, emailnotice, camerasensitivity, axisuser, axispass, axisip, axisport)
{

if (mydiv.find("form").length) {
    mydiv.show();
} else {
    // fields
    var $myform = $("<form id='EditCameraForm' name='' method='post' action='" + to + "'></form>");
    var $myfieldset = $("<fieldset><legend>Edit camera settings</legend></fieldset>");
    var $myinput = $('<input/>').attr('type','hidden').attr('name','camera_type').val(cameratype);
    var $mylabel = $("<label for='CameraName'>Camera name:&nbsp;</label>");
    var $myinput2 = js('<input/>').attr('size','25').attr('name','camera_name').attr('id','CameraName').val(decodeURIComponent(cameraname));
    $myform.append($myinput, $mylabel, $myinput2);
...
}
...
}
```

I've tried using rawurlencode/decodeURIComponent as above and when I hit the edit button if the camera name is called: `a"a` (just testing the quotes) I get `a&quot;a`.  Backslashes such as `a\b` just returns some weird characters back.

If I try:

```
<?php echo json_encode($result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]); ?>
```

and don't put anything in the javascript code I get this error:

`missing ) after argument list`

`edit(this, "/dashboard", "WEBCAM", ""a"a"", "0", "3dd10c49784e2207de1e1932958bfb...`
Where it is pointing to the ""a"a"".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in effect outputting a javascript string literal, so using `htmlentities` is not the correct thing to do. What you need instead is [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php):

```
<?php echo addslashes($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>
```

**Edit:** It goes without saying that you also need to do this for the other two strings you are echoing.

The reason this is correct is that the escape sequences for [Javascript string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#String_literals) are compatible with what `addslashes` does, if you ignore the fact that `addslashes` also escapes the "null" character. However, there's no way that character will be part of your URL so there is a perfect match between what `addslashes` does and what Javascript expects from its string literals.

For completeness I should mention that an appropriate usage of `htmlentities` is to process text that is being sent as part of HTML content; even then, [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) (which performs a small subset of the work of `htmlentities`) is almost always the better fit.

Comment: I applied this and it give the same error as my description when I used json_encode?

Comment: @Tom: Did you change all three occurrences to `addslashes`?

Answer (score 0):

- rawurlencode() is for converting a string to an URL argument
- htmlentities() is for converting a string to an HTML content

If you'd like to convert a string to a Javascript string it should be :

```
function f_str_2js($x) {
  return str_replace( array("\n","\r","\t","'",'"') , array('\n','\r','\t',"\\'",'\"') , $x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the above answers are correct, but you should consider to add your data to a php array or object, than jsonencode and add it to a date-attribute  `date-camera='{...`  than do eventbinding by using jQuery .on(.

This way you can access the data via `$(this).data('camera')`. It will be easy to extend you app without adding more and more parameters to the onclick-function.

for more information see:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/
http://api.jquery.com/on/